dayjs validate post- or ante-meridiem fails
For some reason, this validation fails in dayjs:
dayjs('10:30 AM', 'hh:mm A').isValid()

I tried in multiple browsers and with the latest dayjs version.

Are you using the CustomParseFormat plugin, per the String + Format documentation?

Adding customParseFormat plugin solved the issue:
var customParseFormat = require("dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat");
// import customParseFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat' // ES 2015

dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);

